# Javascript: "Share button" opens and closes on both comment boxes (jsfiddle)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

Javascript: Problem "Share button" opens and closes on both comment boxes (jsfiddle)? Please check example on jsfiddle or show snippet view.

When share button is clicked on, it opens the list items on other comment boxes and I don't understand how to add a fix.

https://jsfiddle.net/64t88uze/2

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".share-list" ).toggle(); 
});
```

```css
/*share buttons on each post*/
.share{float:left;list-style: none;padding: 0 10px 0 0px;margin: 0px; text-align:center; background-color:white;}
.share li {display: block;position: relative;width:80px}
.share ul {display: none;}
.share a {text-decoration: none;display: block;box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) inset;text-decoration: none;white-space: nowrap;color:#fff!important; border-radius:5%;}
.share ul li a:hover {text-decoration: none;}

.share  li:hover li {float: none;}
.share-list {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.COMMENTBOX{height:300px; background-color:#F1F1F1;}
.COMMENTBOX2{height:300px; background-color:#D1D1D1;}
.share-list a :hover{background-color:grey;transition: 0.3s ease}
.share-list a {box-shadow: none;border-radius:0px;}
.fa.fa-facebook,.fa.fa-twitter,.fa.fa-google-plus{font-size:40px; text-align:center; color:#fff;padding:20px; display:block;}

.share button {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.fa-share-alt {color: #02bf03;padding: 10px;}
.fa.fa-facebook{background-color:#3A5795;}
.fa.fa-twitter{background-color:#26C4F1;}
.fa.fa-google-plus{background-color:#E93F2E; border-bottom-left-radius:5%;border-bottom-right-radius:5%;}
.share h3 {display: inline;padding-right:10px;}

/*end*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="COMMENTBOX"> 
<h1>Comment Box 1</h1>
<div class="share">
    <li><a href="#"><button id="shareit"><h3><i class="fa fa-share-alt faa-pulse animated"></i>Share</h3></button></a>
    <ul class="share-list">
        
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
   
   </ul>
         </li>
    </div>
     
     </DIV>

 <div class="COMMENTBOX2"> 
<h1>Comment Box 2</h1>
<div class="share">
    <li><a href="#"><button id="shareit"><h3><i class="fa fa-share-alt faa-pulse animated"></i>Share</h3></button></a>
    <ul class="share-list">
        
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
   
   </ul>
         </li>
    </div>
     
     </DIV>
```

Comment: You HTML is invalid for many reasons.

Comment: The html is just a demo mark-up I wrote to show the actual problem.

Comment: Especially demo HTML should ***never*** be invalid to make sure that is not one of the problem sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.share').find('.share-list').toggle();
});
```

The scope in your code referes to each and every item called `.share-list`. You have to select the `.share-list` in the clicked element.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem. Thank you very much Dimal Chandrasiri! I tried various combination and tried targetting active states, it was doing my head in. Thank you for additional information. This was why I was going horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This addition adds hides "share buttons" when user clicks outside them.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.share').find('.share-list').toggle();
});

$("html").click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.share, .share-list').length === 0) {
        $('.share-list').hide();
    }
});
```